# How to access Session variables and set them in javascript-asp.net mvc?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
<script>
var x="MVC";
@Session["test"] = x;
alert(@Session["test"]);
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Set it from controller action which returns view, and use `ViewBag` to display it, e.g. `var msg = '@ViewBag.Test'` and `alert(msg)` (use `ViewBag.Test = Session["test"].ToString();` in controller action first)

Comment: `Session` is server side code - you cannot set it in JavaScript (client side code)

Answer (score 0):

Session is a server side object. You cannot access it directly in the client side. However you can do it like below.

**Set Session Variable**

Write a new controller action like below.

```
 public void SetSessionVariable(string key, string value)
        {               
            Session[key] = value;
        }
```

Make an ajax call to this action from javascript like below.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: $('#rootUrl').val() + "Controller/SetSessionVariable",
        async: false,
        data: {
            key: "test",
            value: "MVC"
        },
        success: function (data) {
             //Your code
        }
    })
```